# Passwordless authentication not working

Tags: unix, ssh, sftp, sshd

I am trying to setup a passwordless authentication between my webserver & a reporting server using the below steps. It works fine in my dev environment , however in the customer environment it doesn't.

---

Steps :

As testUser user on web server :

```
mkdir ~/.ssh

cd ~/.ssh

ssh-keygen (use default file location and empty passphrase)

ssh-keygen -t dsa (as before)
```

Transfer the generated public keys to Reporting server.

As testUser user -

```
sftp testUser@<ReportServerName>

put id_dsa.pub

put id_rsa.pub

quit
```

Do the following steps on the Reporting server.

As testUser user

```
mkdir ~/.ssh

cd ~/.ssh

cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys

cat ~/id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys2

rm ~/id_*.pub

chmod 644 auth*
```

As root user
    vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Uncomment ‘PubkeyAuthentication yes’

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

---

After doing these steps when I try to a sftp testUser@ it still asks me for a password.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Not a programming question, ask it to superuser community.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: search for "super user" on the left menu in the top bar.